# the html part is not displaying in visual studio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color:black
}
.nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col.menu_fixed {
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        background-color:aqua
    }
body .container.body .right_col {
    background: #F7F7F7;
}
.nav-md .container.body .right_col {
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
    margin-left: 230px;
}
.nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
    display: none;
}
.nav-md .container.body .right_col {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.site_title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ECF0F1 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    line-height: 59px;
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
    .site_title:hover, .site_title:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .site_title i {
        border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
        padding: 5px 6px;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
.left_col {
    background: #2A3F54;
}
.nav_title {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    background: #2A3F54;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 57px;
}
```

```html
<body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">
            <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
                <div class="left_col scroll-view">
                     <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
              <a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>Gentellela Alela!</span></a>
            </div>
                </div>  
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

Whatever  is present within navbar nav-title is not displayed.I cannot understand why the content would not display.I need a side menu with this title on top.But I am first trying to make this display.what is wrong here.

Comment: You should fix your typo as well: nav_title => nav-title

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line from your css code:

```
.nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
    display: none;
```

or use this code:

```
.nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
        display: block;
```

Here is Jsfiddle: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/1wrm2kb2/)

Comment: did it.still it is not displaying

Comment: @nimmy use block instead of none, if you set none for class .nav-md it's not displaying

Comment: i did that..but still it does not display.in the design mode i can see container body in the left and  navbar in the right like unrelated..when i run its blank

Comment: this code renders output in the jsfiddle but not in my browser

Comment: @nimmy what browser are you using?